# Python | Read from multiple csv files and add to a nested list

Tags: python, list, pandas, csv, nested-lists

I have csv files (present in the same directory) like these:

File1:

```
Id,Param1,Param2
1,10,12
2,16,18
3,24,28
4,22,26
```

File2:

```
Id,Param1,Param2
1,13,19
2,15,23
3,21,25
```

I want to read the files and create nested lists like this:

```
Param1 = [[10, 16, 24, 22], [13, 15, 21]]
Param2 = [[12, 18, 28, 26], [19, 23, 25]]
```

What I tried:

```
for i in range(1,nof+1,1):
    with open("File%i.csv" %i, "rb") as f1:
        reader = csv.reader(f1)

        for row in reader:
            Param1.append(row[1])
            Param2.append(row[2])
```

Finally:

```
[Param1[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(Param1), n)]
[Param2[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(Param2), n)]
```

Would work fine if I had the same number of rows in all my files, but that isn't the case. My files have unequal number of rows. So, can someone please help me figure out how to go about creating these splits. Many thanks.

Comment: your inputs aren't csv files. please edit to show actual input, not their excel representaton

Comment: I  don't understand. The "actual input" would be the comma separated values of these same "excel format" numbers.

Comment: exactly. So we can reproduce & fix your issue without having to write those inputs ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
nof = 2
for i in range(1, nof+1, 1):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv("File{}.csv".format(i)))

param1_list = [list(df['Param1']) for df in dfs]
param2_list = [list(df['Param2']) for df in dfs] 

print(param1_list)
print(param2_list)
```

[try it here](https://repl.it/repls/AlertSmartProspect)

Comment: I was trying to avoid using pandas, but I have to admit, it's pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

Modified the sample input a bit.

```
cat file1
1|10|12
2|16|18
3|24|28
4|22|26

cat file2
1|13|19
2|15|23
3|21|25
```

Sample code

```
def process(filename):
    first_list = []
    second_list = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            line = line.rstrip()
            dummy, first_field, second_field = line.split('|')
            first_list.append(first_field)
            second_list.append(second_field)

        return [first_list, second_list]

print (process('file1'))
print (process('file2'))
```

Output

```
[['10', '16', '24', '22'], ['12', '18', '28', '26']]
[['13', '15', '21'], ['19', '23', '25']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using dictionaries and `csv.reader`:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

file1 = StringIO("""Id Param1 Param2
1   10     12
2   16     18
3   24     28
4   22     26""")

file2 = StringIO("""Id Param1 Param2
1   13     19
2   15     23
3   21     25""")

res = {}
for i, file in enumerate([file1, file2]):
    # replace file with open('...', 'r')
    with file as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
        next(reader)  # exclude header row
        res[i] = {idx: list(map(int, x)) for idx, x in enumerate(zip(*reader))}

Param1 = [res[0][1], res[1][1]]
Param2 = [res[0][2], res[1][2]]

print(Param1, Param2, sep='\n')

[[10, 16, 24, 22], [13, 15, 21]]
[[12, 18, 28, 26], [19, 23, 25]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
... from csv import DictReader
... 
... 
... def solution(filenames):
...     result = defaultdict(list)
...     for filename in filenames:
...         d = defaultdict(list)
...         with open(filename, 'r') as f:
...             reader = DictReader(f)
...             for line in reader:
...                 for k, v in line.items():
...                     d[k].append(int(v))
... 
...         for k, v in d.items():
...             result[k].append(v)
...     return result
... 
>>> result = solution(['file1.csv', 'file2.csv'])
>>> result['Param1']
[[10, 16, 24, 22], [13, 15, 21]]
>>> result['Param2']
[[12, 18, 28, 26], [19, 23, 25]]
```